# rails4 behavior based on link_to is nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

There is a `website` attr on `product_lead` table which is optional. If it's present then I wanna turn `@produc_lead.lead` into a link, but if it's not it should be plain text.

If I use the code below and the website is nil then the link points to the page the user is currently on. If I do it with `@product_lead.try(:website)`, it's gonna be the same. But as I mentioned I would like to have plain text over link in this case.

```
<%= link_to @product_lead.website, target: "_blank" do %>
  <%= @product_lead.lead %>
<% end %>
```

After playing around I fell back to the following solution, but it's terrible. Any better ideas?

```
<% if @product_lead.website %>
  <%= link_to @product_lead.website, target: "_blank" do %>
    <%= @product_lead.lead %>
  <% end %>
<% else %>
  <%= @product_lead.lead %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe [link_to_if](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.1/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/link_to_if) if Rails 4

```
<%= link_to_if(@product_lead.website, @product_lead.lead, @product_lead.website) do %>
     @product_lead.lead
<%= end %>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create custom view helper for this.

Answer (score 2):

Well, `link_to` is going to generate a `<a>` tag, whether you provide a valid URL or not. So if the URL is nil, yes, it's gonna be a link for you own page.

If you want to "hide" this, you could call a partial in which you place you if/else and so on, but it's just to sweep this under the rug :)

Or if you wanna go further, as @Jovica Šuša, a view helper is the most elegant solution.